# Передача файлов

Tags: java, клиент-сервер

Всем привет, я новичок в Java, подскажите, пожалуйста, как в Java передавать любой файл с клиента на сервер? Очень был бы признателен.

Код Сервера:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket servsock = new ServerSocket(3128);
    File myFile = new File("D://2Kyrs//Kyrsovik//server//file.txt");
    while (true) {
        Socket sock = servsock.accept();
        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(myFile));
        bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
        OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
        os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
        os.flush();
        sock.close();
    }
}
```

Код клиента:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Socket sock = new Socket("localhost", 3128);
    byte[] mybytearray = new byte[1024];
    InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D://2Kyrs//Kyrsovik//client//file.txt");
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    int bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
    bos.write(mybytearray, 0, bytesRead);
    bos.close();
    sock.close();
}
```

Но данный код не работает, да, и как я понимаю он для передачи только текстового файла

Comment: Что именно "не работает"? Чтобы разобраться в том, что делает этот код, достаточно почитать документацию по используемым в коде классам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы считываете только первый килобайт файла из сокета, после чего все закрываете. Разумеется, у вас не будет ничего работать. Вам следовало бы читать из сокета в цикле, до тех пор пока не будет достигнут конец потока.

По поводу же "работает только с текстовыми файлами" - кто вам сказал такое? Где у вас в коде есть хоть одна операция с `char`? Вы же всюду массивы байт гоняете.

PS зачем вы буферизуете файловый ввод-вывод? Это требуется только при чтении-записи небольшими порциями - вы же пишите в файл килобайтовыми кусками, а читаете так вообще сразу весь файл. Буферизация в таком алгоритме не нужна.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас постараюсь исправить. Мне бы хотелось писать небольшими порциями, для передачи больших файлов. И сделать возможность чтения и записи у сервера и клиента